# Javascript: Find time taken by a function with aysnc calls

Tags: javascript

I need to do profiling(time taken) for a code snippet in Javascript which includes nested hierarchies of functions and many XHR calls which depend on if/else conditions. Is there a way I can measure time for them without measuring each individual call.

I see many solutions using `console.time()` and `performance.now()` but they don't count for asnyc calls.

Comment: try console.time() at start and console.timeEnd() inside the async Function where it ends

Comment: but my function calls another function, which calls another function, which has multiple functions with each having their own XHR call.

Comment: and they call functions based on conditions so call may happen or maynot. Isn't a way to wrap it all, and whatever calls happen they would be accounted for.

Comment: `performance.now()` is incredibly quick and accurate with a very small footprint, do you have thousands of XHR calls? Add `async` keyword to your declared functions.

Comment: not thousands, but 4 or 5 but this are called in a nested way, loops, conditions. And performance.now() doesn't account for that.